# Images not fitting on page, needs to additionally be above all content

Tags: html, css

Currently working on a little project, I have removed the necessary css and html to make it easier to understand my issue.

Nevertheless,

I'm simply trying to get the images to align onto the page correctly. 
In addition, wondered if it would be possible to make the position of the images always show above any other sort of content.

[image: going off the site with no content]

[image: content added, simply not drawing above it]

All help/suggestions would be very much appreciated!

```css
#app-illustrations{pointer-events:none;position:absolute;display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;width:1287px;left:50%;margin-left:-644px;-webkit-transform:scale(.5) rotate(-12deg) translateX(50px);transform:scale(.5) rotate(-12deg) translateX(50px);-webkit-transform-origin:50% 20%;transform-origin:50% 20%}
#app-illustrations.hidden-preload{visibility:hidden}
#app-illustrations div{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;-ms-flex-pack:center;justify-content:center;-webkit-box-align:center;-ms-flex-align:center;align-items:center;border-radius:38px;background:#fff;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 4px 7px 1px #fff,inset 0 -5px 20px rgba(173,186,204,.25),0 2px 6px rgba(0,21,64,.14),0 10px 20px rgba(0,21,64,.05);box-shadow:inset 0 4px 7px 1px #fff,inset 0 -5px 20px rgba(173,186,204,.25),0 2px 6px rgba(0,21,64,.14),0 10px 20px rgba(0,21,64,.05)}
#app-illustrations .tablet-landscape{width:512px;height:352px;margin:115px 50px 0}
#app-illustrations .phone-big{display:none}
#app-illustrations .phone-small{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;-ms-flex-order:-1;order:-1;width:225px;height:467px}
#app-illustrations .tablet-portrait{width:450px;height:675px;margin-top:115px}@media (min-width:670px){
#app-illustrations{-ms-flex-wrap:wrap;flex-wrap:wrap;width:512px;margin-left:-50px;top:215px;-webkit-transform:rotate(-12deg);transform:rotate(-12deg);-webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;transform-origin:100% 0}
#app-illustrations.hidden-preload{visibility:visible}
#app-illustrations [class^=tablet]{margin:0}
#app-illustrations .tablet-landscape{width:512px;height:352px}
#app-illustrations .phone-small{width:225px;height:467px;margin:0 0 50px 176px}
#app-illustrations .tablet-portrait{display:none}}@media (min-width:880px){
#app-illustrations{width:829px;margin-left:-10px;top:20px}
#app-illustrations .tablet-landscape{-ms-flex-item-align:end;align-self:flex-end;margin-right:50px}
#app-illustrations .phone-big{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;width:267px;height:553px}
#app-illustrations .phone-small{-webkit-box-ordinal-group:1;-ms-flex-order:0;order:0;margin:50px 50px 0 0}
#app-illustrations .tablet-portrait{display:-webkit-box;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;width:450px;height:675px;margin-top:50px}}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<section id="app-illustrations" class="hidden-preload">
  <div class="tablet-landscape">
    <img alt="slack" src="img/v3/home/app-illustrations/slack.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="phone-big">
    <img alt="digitalocean" src="img/v3/home/app-illustrations/digitalocean.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="phone-small">
    <img alt="postmates" src="img/v3/home/app-illustrations/postmates.svg">
  </div>
  <div class="tablet-portrait">
    <img alt="asana" src="img/v3/home/app-illustrations/asana.svg">
  </div>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

IMAGES HERE: https://ufile.io/y0yj1
They are SVG's can't add to project!

Comment: where are you hosting the svg images, would be handy to have a working example.

Comment: sorry. https://ufile.io/y0yj1 they are svg's, can't add to post

Comment: Try changing display property from flex to block or inline-block.

Comment: An `<img>` tag is primarily set to `display: inline`, which essentially lies "inline" with the rest of the content. If you want the image to create a new line (or "block") in the page and make sure the rest of the content goes above/below it, use `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand your question, but is this is what you want? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZqdvOW?editors=1100

I just added

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

and placed the html below content in another section:

```
<section id="app-content">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur a....
  </p>
</section>
```

Comment: How could I make it so it doesn't go off the page? It simply needs to fit on it, without expanding.